# UTXO selection strategy

Tags: algorithm, go, bitcoin

I need to apply a specific strategy in selecting UTXO's.
The strategy should minimize the usage of utxo as much as possible.
The boundary of this strategy should be set, ideally, less number of utxo should be favoured until a 10x ratio.

In order to make problem simpler let's assume, there is a slice of integers list := []int{} and I need to find element 'target' where:
list[index] = target, if such element doesnt exist then I need to find first element from slice which is greater than target but needs to be <= target*10

If I am not able to find such element then I need to find two elements x, y where:
x + y = target, if such elements dont exists I need to find first two elements from slice which are greater than target but needs to be <= target*10

If I am not able to find such elements then I need to find three elements x, y, z where:
x + y + z = target, if such elements dont exists I need to find first three elements from slice which are greater than target but needs to be <= target*10

If I am not able to find such three element, I need to find four, five ... up to len(list).

Example 1:

```
target = 6
list := []int {1,2, 6, 10}
result = list[2] = 6
```

Example 2:

```
target = 6
list := []int {1,2, 3, 10}
result = list[3] = 10
```

Example 3:

```
target = 6
list := []int {1,2, 3, 10}
result = list[3] = 10
```

Example 4:

```
target = 6
list := []int {1,3, 3, 61}
result = list[1]  + list[2]= 6
```

Please see below test case which I need to improve with recursion or somehow in order to have generic solution:

```
func Test_SelectUtxo(t *testing.T){
    x := 6

    list := []int{1, 2, 3, 64, 65, 62, 62, 62, 61, 59}
    
    fmt.Println("ONE = x")
    for i := 0; i < len(list) - 1; i ++ {
        if list[i] == x {
            fmt.Println(i)
            break
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("ONE <= x*10")
    for i := 0; i < len(list); i ++ {
        if list[i] > x {
            if list[i] <= x*10 && list[i] > x {
                fmt.Println(list[i])
                break
            }
        }
    }


    fmt.Println("TWO = x")
    out:
    for i := 0; i < len(list) - 1; i ++ {
        for j:=i + 1; j < len(list); j ++ {
            if list[i] + list[j] == x {
                fmt.Println(i)
                fmt.Println(j)
                break out
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Println()

    fmt.Println("TWO <= x*10")
    out1:
    for i := 0; i < len(list) - 1; i ++ {
        for j:=i + 1; j < len(list); j ++ {
            if list[i] + list[j] <= x*10 && list[i] + list[j] > x {
                fmt.Println(i)
                fmt.Println(j)
                break out1
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Println()

    fmt.Println("THREE = x")
    out2:
    for i := 0; i < len(list) - 2; i ++ {
        for j:=i + 1; j < len(list) - 1; j ++ {
            for k:= j + 1; k < len(list); k ++ {
                if list[i] + list[j] + list[k] == x {
                    fmt.Println(i)
                    fmt.Println(j)
                    fmt.Println(k)
                    break out2
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One solution:**

1. set `size = 1`
2. uses **Recursion** (function name=**getCombination** in below snippet) to get all combinations for `size` elements in the input Array.
3. check each combination if meet the requirements from **0 -> i**, if yes, return it (**finish**)
4. if none of combination matches, then `size++`, then goto **Step 2**.

**Snippet:**

```
import (
  "fmt"
)
var combination = []int{}
func GetCombination(src []int,size int, offset int) [][]int { // get all combinations for **size** elements in the elements of src array
  result := [][]int{}
  if size == 0 {
    temp := make([]int, len(combination))
    copy(temp, combination)
    return append(result, temp)
  }
  for i:=offset; i<=len(src) - size; i++ {
    combination = append(combination, src[i])
    temp := GetCombination(src, size-1, i+1)
    result = append(result, temp...)
    combination = combination[:len(combination)-1]
  }
  return result[:]
}
func sum(items []int) int {
  total := 0
  for _, v := range items {
    total += v
  }
  return total
}
func GetBestPair(items []int, target int) []int {
    for i := 1; i < len(items)+1; i++ {
        result := GetCombination(items, i, 0) // get all possible combinations for 1 -> len(items) elements of Array=items
        // fmt.Println("Combinations for ", i, " elements:", result)
        for j := 0; j < len(result); j++ {
            total := sum(result[j])
            if total < target {
                continue
            }
            if total == target {
                return result[j]
            }
            if total < target*10 {
                return result[j]
            }
        }
    }
    return []int{}
}

func main () {
  fmt.Println("Result", GetBestPair([]int{1, 3, 3, 61}, 6))
}
```

**Output for above test case**

```
Combinations for  1  elements: [[1] [3] [3] [61]]
Combinations for  2  elements: [[1 3] [1 3] [1 61] [3 3] [3 61] [3 61]]
Result: [3 3]
```